# how to parse array inside object through gson in android

Tags: android, json

I want to parse array inside object through GSON.. for Example

```
{
  'title': 'Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases',
  'isbn': '032133678X',
  'authors':[
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Joshua Bloch'
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'Neal Gafter'
    }
  ]
}
```

I am only able to parse only object i.e. title, ISBN and got its value but i don't know how to get the value of authors? Please help ,I am using JSON parsing through GSON in android..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421674/using-gson-to-parse-a-json-array may help you get started :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Authors> lAuthors = new ArrayList<Authors>();
List<Authors> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, lAuthors.getClass());

for (Object a : list)
{
   System.out.println(a);
}
```

This will give you values in class Author's object.

```
public class Author{

    int id;
    String name;
    //getter setter here
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: its okay if there is object inside array but what about other object which is outside Author

Comment: You can have class as per your json response structure. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8679512/1777090) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379387/parsing-json-nested-array-with-gson-on-android). [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169754/parsing-nested-json-data-using-gson), too. :) @dheeraj92

Answer (score 0):

those are usefull links for Nasted JSON parsing examples :

[Parsing JSON nested array with GSON on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379387/parsing-json-nested-array-with-gson-on-android)

http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/